# ¿Como puedo obtener informacion de un Json mediante javaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo el siguiente json desde un api y de `weather` quiero obtener el `main` y `description` para poder imprimirlo en pantalla, pero por consola me aparece "**undefined**".

```
{

    "coord": {
        "lon": -70.65,
        "lat": -33.46
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 803,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "broken clouds",
            "icon": "04d"
        }
    ]
}
```

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3871336&units=metric&APPID=" + apikey,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                vars = data.main;
                temp_c = 'Actual ' + vars.temp + '°C'; //- 273.15  
                temp_f = 1.8 * (vars.temp - 273.15) + 32;
                temp_min = 'Min ' + vars.temp_min + '°C';
                temp_max = 'Max ' + vars.temp_max + '°C';
                ciudad = data.name;
                humidity = vars.humidity + '%';
//                description = vars.main[2];

                $("#temp_c").val(temp_c);
                $("#ciudad").val(ciudad);
                $("#humidity").val(humidity);
                $("#temp_min").val(temp_min);
                $("#temp_max").val(temp_max);
//                $("#main").val(main);
//                $("#description").val(description);

                alert('Mostrando clima en ciudad de: ' + ciudad);
                console.log(temp_c);
                console.log(temp_min);
                console.log(temp_max);
                console.log(ciudad);
                console.log(humidity);


            }
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! ¿Podrías subir lo que has intentado? Así contamos con un punto de partida desde el que poder ayudarte.

Comment: sin tener mas referencias de lo que estas haciendo es dificil darte una respuesta certera, prueba usando: `console.log(weather[0].main)` y `console.log(weather[0].description)`

Comment: Estoy utilizando javasript, y lo quiero mostrar los datos del jason por html
<form name="humedad" id="CONDICION">                   
                <!--                <input type="button" value="Mostrar condicion" id="main" onclick="mostrar()"/>-->
                <input type="text" name="txtDescription" id="html" placeholder="Condicion">
            </form>

Comment: tambien intente usando console.log 
tambien he intentado esto 

$("#main").val(main);
$("#description").val(description);

Comment: que tal si haces un  `console.log(data)` y agregas el resultado a la pregunta

Comment: lo intente y al pintarlo en pantalla en un campo de texto me muestra object Object
y en consola me muestra "undefined"

console.log(data.weather.main);

$("#main").val(data.weather.main);

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolví así, cualquier duda deja tu comentario.

Declare una constante llamada array y lo converti en un array de objetos para que pueda ser iterado por un for o forEach, en mi caso use el segundo.

En el primer forEach, obtienes coord y weather los 2 objetos, desde ese forEach puedes acceder solamente a las propiedades de coord pero no a las de weather ya que estan en un array, en este caso vuelves hacer otro forEach a esa llave para poder ingresar a las propiedades de Weather.

[For Each.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)

```js
const array = 
[{
  coord: {
    lon: -70.65,
    lat: -33.46
  },
  weather: [
    {
      id: 803,
      main: "Clouds",
      description: "broken clouds",
      icon: "04d"
    }
  ]
}
];

console.log(array);

array.forEach(array => {
    console.log(array);
    console.log(array.weather);

    array.weather.forEach(infoWeather => {



        console.log('Main -', infoWeather.main);
        console.log('Description -', infoWeather.description);
        const resultado = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = infoWeather.main;
        const resultado2 = document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = infoWeather.description;
    })



});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="description"></div>
    
    <script src="prueba.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Procura ser más claro con tu respuesta: ¿qué encontraste? ¿por qué hiciste tu cambio? ¿dónde puede aprender más?

Comment: Woooo es que cambio la pregunta, al principio solo puso la primera imagen :L

Comment: Ya lo explique, saludos.

Comment: Funciona, pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es introducir la url de la api que estoy consumiendo para extraer la informacion, como serian los pasos correctos?
De antemano gracias

Comment: La pregunta quedó respondida con esta respuesta Si tienes una segunda, da esta respuesta como aceptada y abre una nueva montando el pertinente escenario para poder reproducir tu problema.

Comment: A que te refieres con introducir la url de la api? No entendí bien.